# Button (using <button> tag) does not display in Opera

Tags: html, button, opera

On my website I am using the html 'button' tag but the button does not display when page is opened in Opera version 12.15. Works fine in chrome, firefox and IE.
If you go to my cdn test site [CDN Comparison](http://tryme.in/) u see cloudflare, incapsula and page speed images. below the three cdn images there's a button which does not display. It's supposted to be right above the 'Test and monitor image load speed of the top three Free CDN Service providers' sentence. please help.

```
<button id="button" onclick="changeLink()">Test Another Image</button>
```

I have not added any style to this tag using CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Opera doesn't like showing the native-look button background on an element with both `border-radius` and `border` styles set, but no `background-color`.

To make it work you either need to specify a `background-color` for the element, or remove/override either the `border-radius` or `border` styles defined in style.css near line 208 (at least just for that element).

You can [see the differences](http://jsfiddle.net/winterblood/MPDe8/1/) between the buttons with only very slight differences in style.